# The derivative of a function is square integrable assuming Fourier transform dominated

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

I am struggling in solving the second part of this problem.

Let $g$ be a continuous function in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ whose Fourier transform is the function $F$. Suppose $|F(x)|\leq (1+x^2)^{-2}$. Prove that $g$ is a $C^1$ function such that $d g/d x\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The following gives the main idea.
\begin{eqnarray*}
|F(k)| &\leqslant &\frac{1}{(1+k^{2})^{2}}\Rightarrow F(k)\in L^{1}\cap
L^{\infty } \\
|kF(k)| &\leqslant &|k|\frac{1}{(1+k^{2})^{2}}\Rightarrow H(k)=kF(k)\in
L^{1}\cap L^{\infty }
\end{eqnarray*}
It follows that $g(x)\in L^{1}$ and $g(x)\in L^{2}\cap L^{\infty }$ so $%
g(x)\in L^{1}\cap L^{\infty }$. Also $H(k)\in L^{1}\cap L^{2}$ so
$$h(x)=\int dk\exp [-ikx]H(k)\in L^{2}\cap L^{\infty }
$$
But
$$
h(x)=\int dk\exp [-ikx]kF(k)=i\partial _{x}\int dk\exp [-ikx]F(k)=i\partial
_{x}g(x)
$$

Comment: don't you  need $\partial_xg\in L^1$? This is what I have been struggling with. I wanted to use Folland's Real Analysis, Theorem 8.22 (e), but this is required to use the identity $(\partial_x f)=(2\pi i x)^\alpha \hat{f}$.

Comment: I thought that the aim was to prove that (∂_x)g is contained in the intersection of L^2 and L^∞? This is what follows from the above considerations. That procedure does not lead to an L^1 property and I doubt that it is actually true. What does that theorem actually state?